# How have we found the conditions of the problem from the graph?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following :

$$u_{xx}(x,y)+u_{yy}(x,y)=0$$

[image]

$$u(x,0)=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq l \\ u(0,y)=0, u(x,\pi)=0 \\ u(l,y)=0$$

> How have we found these conditions from the graph??

$$$$

$$u(x,y)=X(x) \cdot Y(y)$$ 
We get the following twp problems:

$$X''(x)+\lambda X(X)=0, 0<x<l \\ X(0)=X(l)=0$$ $$Y''(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0, 0< y < \pi \\ Y(\pi)=0$$

From the first one we find that $\lambda_k=\left (k \frac{\pi}{l}\right )^2$ and $X_k(x)=\sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right )$.

Frm the second one we get that $Y_k(y)=e^{\frac{k\pi}{l}y}-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}-\frac{k \pi}{l}y}$.

So, $$u(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right ) \left (e^{\frac{k\pi}{l}y}-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}-\frac{k \pi}{l}y}\right )$$

$$u(x,0)=f(x) \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right ) \left (1-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}}\right )=f(x) \\ \Rightarrow c_k=\frac{2}{l\left (1-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}}\right )} \int_0^l f(x)\sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right )dx$$

$$$$

I tried to calculate $c_k$ on my own and I got stuck...

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right ) \left (1-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}}\right )=f(x) \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right ) \left (1-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}}\right )\sin (mx) =f(x) \sin (mx) \\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \left (1-e^{2\frac{k \pi^2}{l}}\right ) \int_0^l \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right )\sin (mx) dx =\int_0^l f(x) \sin (mx) dx$$

$$$$

$$\int_0^l \sin \left (k \frac{\pi}{l}x\right )\sin (mx) dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^l \left (\cos ((\frac{k\pi}{l}-m)x)-\cos((\frac{k\pi}{l}+m)x)\right )dx=\frac{1}{2}\left [\frac{\sin ((\frac{k\pi}{l}-m)x)}{\frac{k\pi}{l}-m}-\frac{\sin ((\frac{k\pi}{l}+m)x)}{\frac{k\pi}{l}+m}\right ]_0^l=\frac{1}{2}\left (\frac{\sin ((\frac{k\pi}{l}-m)l)}{\frac{k\pi}{l}-m}-\frac{\sin ((\frac{k\pi}{l}+m)l)}{\frac{k\pi}{l}+m}\right )=-\frac{k \pi}{l}\cos (k \pi) \sin (ml)$$

But I should have the result that it equal to $0$ for $k \neq \frac{lm}{\pi}$, or not??

What have I done wrong??

Comment: Your boundary conditions have nothing to do with the boundary itself. These are conditions that are imposed *ad hoc* to model the specific problem we have in mind. If I recall correctly, Laplace's equation is often used in the study of electric potentials. In your case, the value of $u$ on the boundary being zero on the left, top and right would mean that the potential is zero there. A physical interpretation might be that there is no charge on the outside, but that there are a bunch of electrons on the bottom which are the source of the potential on the inside.

Comment: So, we cannot conclude from a graph which the conditions of the problem are, right?? @CameronWilliams

Comment: @MaryStar That's right: you can impose a variety of different types of boundary conditions on a PDE in a bounded domain. For instance you might put a homogeneous Neumann condition on the other three sides, and a Dirichlet condition on the bottom. Physically this would correspond to the equilibrium state of a box which is insulated from the outside on three sides and in thermal contact with a heat bath at the bottom.

Comment: @MaryStar That is exactly right. You only know what the boundary *is*, not what the boundary conditions are.

Answer (score 1):

I am starting from

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{l} \right ) \left ( 1 - e^{\frac{2 k \pi^2}{l}} \right ) = f(x).$$

I didn't actually check your work to this point, so be sure to check that. From there, the left side is in the form of a Fourier sine series for $f$. (Note that $f$ depends on $x$, which lives in $[0,l]$, not in $[0,\pi]$, so the basis functions are $\left \{ \sin \left ( \frac{k \pi x}{l} \right ) \right \}_{k=1}^\infty$, not $\left \{ \sin(mx) \right \}_{m=1}^\infty$.) This means that $c_k \left ( 1 - e^{\frac{2 k \pi^2}{l}} \right )$ must be the $k$th Fourier sine coefficient of $f$, which is $\frac{2}{l} \int_0^l f(x) \sin \left ( \frac{k \pi x}{l} \right )$. Now rearrange to get $c_k$.

Comment: I see... Thank you for your answer!! :-)   @Ian